# Split string into a hash of hashes (perl)

Tags: perl, path

at the moment im a little confused..

I am looking for a way to write a string with an indefinite number of words (separated by a slash) in a recursive hash.

These "strings" are output from a text database.

Given is for example
"office/1/hardware/mouse/count/200"

the next one can be longer or shorter..

This must be created from it:

```
{
    office {
        1{
            hardware {
                mouse {
                    count => 200
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What is the point of such a hash? What are you trying to use it for? Technically, it is not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Work backwards. Split the string.  Use the last two elements to make the inner-most hash.  While more words exist, make each one the key of a new hash, with the inner hash as its value.

```
my $s = "office/1/hardware/mouse/count/200";

my @word = split(/\//, $s);

# Bottom level taken explicitly
my $val = pop @word;
my $key = pop @word;

my $h = { $key => $val };

while ( my $key = pop @word )
{
    $h = { $key => $h };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!
Thats exactly what i needed.
I really thought it's more difficult, but your code is very simple!
Thanks for that !

Comment: This will clobber records if you have more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Simple recursive function should do

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub foo {
    my $str = shift;
    my ($key, $rest) = split m|/|, $str, 2;
    if (defined $rest) {
        return { $key => foo($rest) };
    } else {
        return $key;
    }
}
my $hash = foo("foo/bar/baz/2");
print Dumper $hash;
```

Gives output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => {
                     'bar' => {
                                'baz' => '2'
                              }
                   }
        };
```

But like I said in the comment: What do you intend to use this for? It is not a terribly useful structure.

Comment: I need to get a text based database (astdb or asterisk database) into a hash. With this hash I want to display this database in the web interface.

Your code is working, but I don't like self calling subs. Therefore I prefer Bob's variant.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

If there are many lines to be read into a single hash and the lines have a variable number of fields, you have big problems and the other two answers will clobber data by either smashing sibling keys or overwriting final values.  I'm supposing this because there is no rational reason to convert a single line into a hash.

You will have to walk down the hash with each field.  This will also give you the most control over the process.

```perl
our $hash = {};
our $eolmark = "\000";
while (my $line = <...>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @fields = split /\//, $line;
  my $count = @fields;
  my $h = $hash;
  my $i = 0;
  map { (++$i == $count) ?
   ($h->{$_}{$eolmark} = 1) :
   ($h = $h->{$_} ||= {});
  } @fields;
}
```

`$h->{$_}{$eolmark} = 1` You need the special "end of line" key so that you can recognize the end of a record and still permit longer records to coexist.  If you had two records
`foo/bar/baz foo/bar/baz/quux`, the second would overwrite the final value of the first.

`$h = $h->{$_} ||= {}` This statement is a very handy idiom to both create and populate a cache in one step and then take a shortcut reference to it.  Never do a hash lookup more than once.

HTH